# How variables inside braces are evaluated

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm new to shell scripting and I came across these expressions

`${var:-val}` and `${var-val}`

`${var:+val}` and `${var+val}`

`${var:=val}` and `${var=val}`

so how are they evaluated and what are the differences between them

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are all various forms of parameter expansion with alternatives:

- `${var:-val}` is replaced by `val` if `var` is unset or null, `${var}` otherwise (so `val` is a "default value");
- `${var:=val}` first assigns `val` to `var` if `var` is unset or null, and then (in all cases) is replaced by `${var}`;
- `${var:+val}` is replaced with *nothing* if `var` is unset or null, `val` otherwise.

Omitting the `:` drops the "or null" part of all these definitions.

This is all described in the [`bash(1)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), and in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Some examples might help:

```
unset a
echo "${a:-default}"
```

produces `default`, as does `echo "${a-default}"`.

```
a=
echo "${a:-default}"
```

again produces `default`, but `echo "${a-default}"` outputs a blank line.

```
a=test
echo "${a:-default}"
```

produces `test`, as does `echo "${a-default}"`.

```
unset a
echo "${a:=default}"
```

produces `default`, and `a` is now `default` (as confirmed by `echo "${a}"`).

The `+` form might seem strange, but it is useful when constructing variables in several steps:

```
PATH="${PATH}${PATH:+:}/blah/bin"
```

will add `:` before `/blah/bin` only if `PATH` is non-empty, which avoids having a path starting with `:`.

Comment: The `:+` form is also useful for avoiding placing the empty string as an argument on a command line, while still properly double-quoting the variable.  e.g. `grep ${ignorecase:+"$ignorecase"} ... `.  The other, worse, alternative is to just use `$ignorecase` unquoted on the cmd line...which is only safe if you know **exactly** what `$ignorecase` can contain.